# Update and delete an object within an array of a Pinia store in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, pinia

I am making a CRUD in Vue 3 and I am using **Pinia** to save my objects as an array. Everything works fine but already when I want to update one of the objects I get the error of:

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "id" failed: target is readonly

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "length" failed: target is readonly

In my store I define my array as follows:

```
const companies = ref<Company[]>([])
```

In my composable since I have the object with the updated data stored in **data.data** and the **id** parameter which is an attribute of the object I try to do the following:

```
const { companies } = store
const index = companies.findIndex(c => c.id = id)
if(index > -1)
     companies.splice(index, 1, data.data)
store.setCompanies(companies)
```

However, it is in the **splice** method that gives me this error, whether I want to use it to replace the object or to remove it from the array.
I have seen that there is a **store.$patch** method but I do not know if it applies to this case, and if I wanted to apply a filter and then replace the entire array in the long run that are many objects I don't see it convenient.

Comment: What's the purpose of store.setCompanies(companies) ? You either mutate companies directly (which is not a good practice) or do this with an action, not both. Probably the array needs to be copied instead

Comment: you have to call `storeToRefs` in order to make the companies reactive outside the store. 
checkL https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/index.html#using-the-store